# What is the difference between String and NSMutableString?

Tags: swift, string, nsstring, nsmutablestring

What is the difference between String and NSString?

Comment: There's no reason for you to use NSMutableString, so don't. This is Swift, not Objective-C. Always use the Foundation bridged type, not the Objective-C type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` is a Swift native type, and uses value semantics.

`NSMutableString` is a Foundation Class object that is "toll-free-bridged" with the Swift `String` type. As a Class object it uses reference semantics.

The `NSMutableString` class has a few methods that the Swift String type does not.

Comment: I'll add that the way they count "by default" there characters are different: UTF16 vs UTF8. So `aString.count` might be different from `aNS(Mutable)String.length`, which is a mistake often done...